# Spring boot 2.0 neo4j ogm 3.0 compatible jetty version

Tags: maven, spring-boot, neo4j, jetty, neo4j-ogm

I'm trying to upgrade spring boot from 1.5 to 2.0 and facing issue with jetty version. I'm new to neo4j ogm and spring boot.

When I try to run a test case it fails with below error.

```
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/server/SessionManager

        at org.neo4j.server.CommunityNeoServer.createWebServer(CommunityNeoServer.java:90)
        at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.init(AbstractNeoServer.java:188)
        at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:204)
        at org.neo4j.harness.internal.InProcessServerControls.start(InProcessServerControls.java:71)
        at org.neo4j.harness.internal.AbstractInProcessServerBuilder.newServer(AbstractInProcessServerBuilder.java:151)
        at org.neo4j.ogm.testutil.TestServer.startServer(TestServer.java:75)
        at org.neo4j.ogm.testutil.TestServer.(TestServer.java:63)
        at org.neo4j.ogm.testutil.TestServer.(TestServer.java:53)
```

and tried simply adding jetty.version referred here in this issue, 
[Spring boot integration test fails with Neo4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42227676/spring-boot-integration-test-fails-with-neo4j).

```
<jetty.version>9.2.9.v20150224</jetty.version>
```

while adding the above on pom.xml, test case alone passing fine which is working as expected. But unable to build the app and ends up with jetty error below.

```
[ERROR]   The project com.example:demo:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT (C:\code\Springboot2.0_Neo4jOGM_Sample\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable import POM: Failure to find org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-bom:pom:9.2.9.v20150224 in https://repo.spring.io/milestone was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of spring-milestone has elapsed or updates are forced @ org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.0.0.RELEASE, C:\Users\nkumar\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-dependencies\2.0.0.RELEASE\spring-boot-dependencies-2.0.0.RELEASE.pom, line 1652, column 25 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]
```

And the code sample can be seen here, 
    https://github.com/nkumarclm/springboot2.0_neo4jogm3.0/

Just would like to know if there are any version compatibility problem on using or any suggestion to run tests with .cql file with provided spring & neo4j ogm versions?

Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Jetty Internal class `org.eclipse.jetty.server.SessionManager`, existed for all versions of Eclipse Jetty 7.0.x thru 9.3.x.

http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cfc%3A%22org.eclipse.jetty.server.SessionManager%22

The class `org.eclipse.jetty.server.SessionManager` was removed in 9.4.x as part of that major version refactor of Session handling.

As for ...

```
Non-resolvable import POM: Failure to find org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-bom:pom:9.2.9.v20150224 ...
```

The `jetty-bom` artifact, as a concept, has existed since Jetty 9.3.19.v20170502, in various bad and unsupported states until it was finally improved at Jetty 9.4.7.v20180619 for the users of spring-boot.

Lets look at the raw dependency tree for [github.com/nkumarclm/springboot2.0_neo4jogm3.0](https://github.com/nkumarclm/springboot2.0_neo4jogm3.0/)

(This is the raw tree, without locally specified versions)

```
$ mvn dependency:tree
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building demo 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:3.0.1:tree (default-cli) @ demo ---
[INFO] com.example:demo:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-neo4j:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.19:runtime
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.data:spring-data-neo4j:jar:5.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:5.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:2.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.4.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.3:test
[INFO] |  |     \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:1.2:test
[INFO] |  |        \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.4:test
[INFO] |  +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
[INFO] |  +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:3.9.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:2.15.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.7.10:test
[INFO] |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:jar:1.7.10:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.6:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.5.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:jar:0.0.20131108.vaadin1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:5.0.4.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  \- org.xmlunit:xmlunit-core:jar:2.5.1:test
[INFO] +- org.projectlombok:lombok:jar:1.16.20:provided
[INFO] +- org.codehaus.janino:janino:jar:3.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.codehaus.janino:commons-compiler:jar:3.0.8:compile
[INFO] +- org.neo4j.driver:neo4j-java-driver:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] \- org.neo4j:neo4j-ogm-test:jar:3.1.0:test
[INFO]    +- org.neo4j:neo4j-ogm-http-driver:jar:3.1.0:test
[INFO]    |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-ogm-api:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.9.4:compile
[INFO]    |  |     +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.9.0:compile
[INFO]    |  |     \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.9.4:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.5:test
[INFO]    |  \- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:compile
[INFO]    +- org.neo4j:neo4j-ogm-core:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.7:compile
[INFO]    |  \- io.github.lukehutch:fast-classpath-scanner:jar:2.7.4:compile
[INFO]    +- org.neo4j:neo4j-ogm-embedded-driver:jar:3.1.0:test
[INFO]    +- org.neo4j:neo4j-ogm-bolt-driver:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO]    +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO]    |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO]    +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:21.0:test
[INFO]    +- org.neo4j.test:neo4j-harness:jar:3.2.9:test
[INFO]    |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j:jar:3.2.9:test
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-lucene-index:jar:3.2.9:test
[INFO]    |  |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-analyzers-common:jar:5.5.0:test
[INFO]    |  |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:jar:5.5.0:test
[INFO]    |  |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-queryparser:jar:5.5.0:test
[INFO]    |  |  |  \- org.apache.lucene:lucene-codecs:jar:5.5.0:test
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-graph-algo:jar:3.2.9:test
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-udc:jar:3.2.9:test
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-cypher:jar:3.2.9:test
[INFO]    |  |  |  +- org.scala-lang:scala-library:jar:2.11.12:test
[INFO]    |  |  |  +- org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:jar:2.11.12:test
[INFO]    |  |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-graph-matching:jar:3.1.3:test
[INFO]    |  |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-codegen:jar:3.2.9:test
[INFO]    |  |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-cypher-compiler-2.3:jar:2.3.11:test
[INFO]    |  |  |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-cypher-frontend-2.3:jar:2.3.11:test
[INFO]    |  |  |  |  \- com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap:concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru:jar:1.4.2:test
[INFO]    |  |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-cypher-compiler-3.1:jar:3.1.6:test
[INFO]    |  |  |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-cypher-frontend-3.1:jar:3.1.6:test
[INFO]    |  |  |  |  \- com.github.ben-manes.caffeine:caffeine:jar:2.6.2:test
[INFO]    |  |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-cypher-compiler-3.2:jar:3.2.9:test
[INFO]    |  |  |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-cypher-frontend-3.2:jar:3.2.9:test
[INFO]    |  |  |  |  \- org.neo4j:neo4j-cypher-ir-3.2:jar:3.2.9:test
[INFO]    |  |  |  +- org.parboiled:parboiled-scala_2.11:jar:1.1.7:test
[INFO]    |  |  |  |  \- org.parboiled:parboiled-core:jar:1.1.7:test
[INFO]    |  |  |  \- net.sf.opencsv:opencsv:jar:2.3:test
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-jmx:jar:3.2.9:test
[INFO]    |  |  \- org.neo4j:neo4j-consistency-check:jar:3.2.9:test
[INFO]    |  +- org.neo4j.app:neo4j-server:jar:3.2.9:test
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j:pom:3.2.9:test
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-security:jar:3.2.9:test
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-dbms:jar:3.2.9:test
[INFO]    |  |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-import-tool:jar:3.2.9:test
[INFO]    |  |  |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.12:test
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-command-line:jar:3.2.9:test
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.neo4j:server-api:jar:3.2.9:test
[INFO]    |  |  |  \- org.neo4j.3rdparty.javax.ws.rs:jsr311-api:jar:1.1.2.r612:test
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-bolt:jar:3.2.9:test
[INFO]    |  |  |  \- io.netty:netty-all:jar:4.1.22.Final:test
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.neo4j.client:neo4j-browser:jar:3.1.4:test
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-shell:jar:3.2.9:test
[INFO]    |  |  |  \- jline:jline:jar:2.12:test
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:jar:9.4.8.v20171121:test
[INFO]    |  |  |  +- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.1.0:test
[INFO]    |  |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:jar:9.4.8.v20171121:test
[INFO]    |  |  |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:jar:9.4.8.v20171121:test
[INFO]    |  |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:jar:9.4.8.v20171121:test
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-webapp:jar:9.4.8.v20171121:test
[INFO]    |  |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-xml:jar:9.4.8.v20171121:test
[INFO]    |  |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:jar:9.4.8.v20171121:test
[INFO]    |  |  |     \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-security:jar:9.4.8.v20171121:test
[INFO]    |  |  +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-server:jar:1.19:test
[INFO]    |  |  +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-servlet:jar:1.19:test
[INFO]    |  |  +- commons-configuration:commons-configuration:jar:1.10:test
[INFO]    |  |  |  +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:test
[INFO]    |  |  |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:test
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-jaxrs:jar:1.9.13:test
[INFO]    |  |  |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.13:test
[INFO]    |  |  |  \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.13:test
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.mozilla:rhino:jar:1.7R4:test
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:jar:1.53:test
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:jar:1.53:test
[INFO]    |  |  \- com.sun.jersey.contribs:jersey-multipart:jar:1.19:test
[INFO]    |  |     \- org.jvnet.mimepull:mimepull:jar:1.9.3:test
[INFO]    |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-common:test-jar:tests:3.2.9:test
[INFO]    |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-kernel:test-jar:tests:3.2.9:test
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-graphdb-api:jar:3.2.9:test
[INFO]    |  |  |  \- org.neo4j:neo4j-resource:jar:3.2.9:test
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-common:jar:3.2.9:test
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-collections:jar:3.2.9:test
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-primitive-collections:jar:3.2.9:test
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-io:jar:3.2.9:test
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-csv:jar:3.2.9:test
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-logging:jar:3.2.9:test
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-lucene-upgrade:jar:3.2.9:test
[INFO]    |  |  |  \- org.apache.lucene:lucene-backward-codecs:jar:5.5.0:test
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-configuration:jar:3.2.9:test
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-index:jar:3.2.9:test
[INFO]    |  |  \- org.neo4j:neo4j-ssl:jar:3.2.9:test
[INFO]    |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-io:test-jar:tests:3.2.9:test
[INFO]    |  |  \- org.neo4j:neo4j-unsafe:jar:3.2.9:test
[INFO]    |  +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-client:jar:1.19:test
[INFO]    |  |  \- com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:jar:1.19:test
[INFO]    |  +- org.neo4j.app:neo4j-server:test-jar:tests:3.2.9:test
[INFO]    |  +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.11:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.9:test
[INFO]    |  \- org.neo4j:neo4j-kernel:jar:3.2.9:test
[INFO]    \- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:test
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.939 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-07-03T12:58:10Z
[INFO] Final Memory: 26M/88M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

From here we learn that the parent `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:2.0.0.RELEASE` has a requirement for `org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:jar:9.4.8.v20171121`.

> Note: Jetty versioning (since 1995) is `<servlet_support>.<major_version>.<minor_version>`

So you have:

- spring-boot requiring a Jetty major version of 9.4.x
- neo4jogm requiring Jetty major version 9.2.x

That's just incompatible.

The project [github.com/nkumarclm/springboot2.0_neo4jogm3.0](https://github.com/nkumarclm/springboot2.0_neo4jogm3.0/) cannot function the way its defined / configured.   It would seem that either neo4jogm should be upgraded to support Jetty 9.4.x, or spring-boot should be downgraded to support Jetty 9.2.x.

In short, you have a bigger issue then merely picking the right version of Jetty.

Answer (score 0):

I tried reaching Neo4j team and here is the response I received.

The root problem is the dependency mismatch between SpringBoot and Neo4j on jetty. The problem occurs because you are using the `MultiDriverTestClass` from the neo4j-ogm-test module.
It will spawn a Neo4j instance that will take request over the given transport mode defined via the protocol you defined in your `ogm.properties` file.
If you would alter your test base to an embedded instance, you could work around the problem:
Remove the `MultiDriverTestClass` inheritance and create a `Configuration` on your own like `Configuration configuration = new Configuration.Builder(new ClasspathConfigurationSource("ogm.properties")).build();`. The content of the `ogm.properties` should be empty to force OGM to create a new temporary embedded instance.